# Split tunneling to speed up Windows update

Tags: vpn, tunneling

We have almost 10 years worth of Win7 updates that need to be done and the amount of bandwith can't be handled by our VPN. Are the security risks of enabling split-tunnel a lot smaller when its just enabled during an update push? Is there any evidence of other companies doing a procedure like this? Is there an alternative to doing something like this?

Comment: In my experience, the vast majority of companies always split-tunnel, which you might call evidence of companies doing something like this. Generally, companies don't ever tunnel Internet destined traffic via the VPN.